# Synchronize ArrayList in or outside of while loop?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, while-loop, synchronized

So i have a pretty simple case:

```
while (resultSet.next())
{
    list.add(...);
}
```

I want to synchronize the list. (`synchronized (list)`)

Now is it better to synchronize the complete while loop? Or should the synchronized block be inside the while loop?

Is there, depending on performance, a relevant difference when he has to lock and release the list on every single loop?

Comment: Have you considered [`Collections.synchronizedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29)?

Comment: @aioobe i have, but there's also a `for (list)` later on.

Comment: ...which you want to synchronize *around*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to add the entries to a new list that no other thread is accessing, then add them all together ( using [addAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll%28int,%20java.util.Collection%29)) to the shared ArrayList once you're done reading from the resultSet. That way you would have to synchronize only once, it would minimize contention with other threads, and you wouldn't be holding the lock while doing I/O.

```
List localList = new ArrayList();
while (resultSet.next()) {
    localList.add(resultSet.get...);
}
synchronized(list) {
    list.addAll(localList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main difference would be that if you lock outside the loop, then other sync operations on the list from other threads will have to wait for the whole loop to finish.

If you just sync inside the loop, other threads can modify the list between inserts.

So the right thing to do would depend on the behaviour you are looking for.

Also, please note that you need to sync on the list in all other places in order for that to work properly. If other threads modify the list without trying to get the lock, they will be able to do so.

To prevent that, you could use a collection that already provides thread safety.

Or you can create the list like this, and not worry about having to synchronize yourself:

```
List aList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideal scenario, you should synchronize only the specific block of code, rather than the entire loop. One can have a seperate synchronized method which could be invoked from the while loop. this allows other thread to continue their execution. if you are not carrying-out any expensive operation (like DB updation), try to seek alternatives as Synchronized blocks affect performance thus its always advisable to use it carefully.